# Docker containers with one public IP

Tags: ssh, docker, ip, assign

I have some Docker containers, that contains several OSes. So I would like to make reacheable (via `SSH`) these containers directly from the Internet. I can use up only one public IP address. Now there is `docker0` in bridge mode with its default IP. How can I configure Docker to make accessible containers separately from everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by mapping each of your containers ssh port to a different port on the public ip address.

Like:

```
$ docker run -d -p 22000:22 --name sshcontainer1 some_image
$ docker run -d -p 22001:22 --name sshcontainer2 some_image
$ docker run -d -p 22002:22 --name sshcontainer3 some_image
...
```

Then you communicate this port [to your customer]. Done.

Comment: It is working, but how can I login? I have tried `passwd` inside container, but it isn't working.

Comment: check your log files in the container (like /var/log/auth.log) what's going on.  This is probably best suited for a new question on serverfault.

Comment: This file seems isn't exists. I try to ask it on SF.

Answer (score 0):

The docker documentation has an example of setting an ssh server.

https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

Comment: That is okay, but port 22 can be mapped only to 1 container at a time.

Comment: I think the document suggests that the port 22 is of the container and that is mapped to some port of the host say 4146, so from there you can ssh using the IP of host and specify the port 4146, this will ssh into the container via the host.

Comment: I got the following error:
`Error: No public port '22/tcp' published for test_sshd`